# Jest test working fine but not updating data in wrapper after await

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am writing my first test in Vue and using jest, the issue I am facing is my function works and I am able to console log the data and see it in the console but the wrapper data has not been updated.

```
async loadcsv(element=null) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  let file = element[0].file
  this.toggleLoading()
  reader.onload = async (e) => {
    try {
      //Normalising headers
      const results = e.target.result
      let resultSplit = results.split('\n')
      const header = resultSplit[0]
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z,]/g, '')
        .trim()
      resultSplit[0] = header
      let table = resultSplit.join('\n') 
      const rows = await d3.csvParse(table) //wrapper data does not update after this line, anything before reflects
      await Promise.all(
        rows.map(async (row) => {
          this.collections.push(row)
        }),
      )
      this.inlineVisibility = false
      this.toggleLoading()
      this.$refs.modal.hide()
    } catch (err) {
      this.toggleLoading()
      this.inlineNotification('error', 'Unable to process CSV', `${err}.`)
    }
  }
  reader.readAsText(file)
},
}
```

However data in the `wrapper.vm.$data` is still empty

```
collection = []
```

where as in the console, it shows

```
collection = [{my test data}]
```

with  `at mockConstructor.reader.onload`

at the end

How do I get the array that shows I the console?

workingCSV is a string of my CSV file

```
describe('ModalAddCollectionCSV', () => {
  it('Test load csv function', async () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    const wrapper = mount(ModalAddCollectionCSV, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        visible: true,
      },
    })
    const readAsTextMock = jest.fn()
    const dataRead = jest.spyOn(global, 'FileReader').mockImplementation(function () {
      const self = this
      this.readAsText = readAsTextMock.mockImplementation(() => {
        self.onload({ target: { result: workingCSV } })
      })
    })
    const data = wrapper.vm.loadcsv()
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data).toContain(data)
  })
```

Comment: The question lacks code for the test

Comment: @EstusFlask added the test code

Comment: As it was already commented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255311/vue-test-method-function-which-changes-data , loadcsv is untestable because it doesn't return a promise that could be awaited in a test. It should return a promise of a result. There should preferably be two functions, one that just loads data and returns it, and another that  uses `this` and updates component data

Comment: @EstusFlask I made it work by making use of timeout, so test pauses till the loadcsv is complete but yeah 2 function probably might be better way to go

Comment: Timeouts are fragile and slow. But basically yes, you can use zero delay timeout like `flush-promises` if all async ops are mocked and expected to resolve immediately

Comment: Oh okay will check that out @EstusFlask thanks